# prototype js event observation carrying to elements children

Tags: scriptaculous, prototypejs

I have a html list as the following:

```
<ul>
 <li id="one">
  <ul id="sub_ul">
   <li>sth</li>
   <li>sth2</li>
   <li>sth3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I observe a click event on "one" in order to SlideUp, SlideDown "sub_ul". The problem is that when the list is open, clicking on any of the sub-elements triggers the SlideUp action. I would naturally like to avoid this. Could anybody please tell me how I can do that?

Cheers,
Manojo

Comment: It says on http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe, that a child may also be affected with the observe function, as "bubbling" is caused. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

In your event handler first check if an item has been clicked.

```
$('one').observe('click', function(event)}{
    if (event.findElement('li') != document) {
        event.stop;
        return;
    }

    // continue normal processing
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, performing this check completely disables the effects. "event.findElement('li')" always refers to $('one') in my case. alert("event.element") does not return the element clicked, but prints some kind of function: "function () {
    var a = update([this], arguments);
    return __method.apply(null, a);
}"

Comment: But actually, thanks to your code above, I was able to figure out a solution. I can do the following: if(event.findElement('ul').id == 'sub_ul'){event.stop(); return;}. Thanks for that!